# write c type matrix to disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a C type matrix of structs in my program. I want to write it in a file for older devices who don't have multitasking.

is there any simple way to write it to disk or do i have to wrap it in a custom object and write that?

an example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSData`'s `dataWithBytes:length:` method to wrap your matrix and write it to file.

```
MyStruct matrix[20][30];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:matrix length:sizeof(matrix)];
[data writeToFile:myFile atomically:YES];

NSData *back = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
MyStruct backMatrix[20][30];
[back getBytes:&backMatrix];
```

Comment: @skytz You do pretty much the same thing in reverse order; take a look at the update.

Comment: I hope these structs don't have any pointers or other non-scalar data in them.

Comment: @KenThomases Absolutely - I assumed plain C structs arranged as a matrix, not a fancy object graph with pointers.

Comment: The second part is broken because because you nowhere check to make sure that the data in the file is small enough to go in the array.

Comment: @JeremyP Good point - this is certainly true for solutions with exposed file system. However, if your program is the only piece of code to ever touch that file, you can be certain that whatever you wrote there last time is precisely what you are reading back. Of course if you're in OS X you'd need to be a lot more careful.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight:  All the same, in production software (as opposed to an SO example), you should probably not assume anything about the files on the file system.